# Seeking for text on the theory of infinite sets

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for some **supplementary material** on the theory of infinite sets, because I always seem to run into trouble with countability arguments in Analysis and Topology. Any recommendations?

**I would prefer something with some problems too if possible.**

Comment: I give a list of several such books in this [5 February 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=224913), and a more complete list is given in [Textbooks on set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490). (I have not checked to see if all those in my list are here, which is why I'm also giving my list.) For more advanced texts, see [Second reading on set theory? Any recommendations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989644)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good book on set theory.  When I took it at Berkeley,  Lloyd Vaught had his own book.  Maybe look it up.

Comment: Do you mean [Robert Vaught](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lawson_Vaught)?

Comment: That must be who.  For the life of me I don't know where I got lloyd...  his class was very enjoyable.   I got an a+.  He took us out for pizza at the end.